# htaccess to disable directory browsing in Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I create a `.htaccess` file with this content: (in the folder of the site)

```
#Disable directory indexes
Options -Indexes
```

But I still see the directories in the browser.

And in `apache2.conf` I rewrite this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I assume you added these directives to your `.htaccess` (two `s`), not `.htacces` as you wrote in your question?

Answer (score 0):

If that didn't work and you got no error then it looks like `.htaccess` files are not enabled on your server. You'll need something like `AllowOverride All` in the server config that controls this area of the filesystem.

At the very least you would need the following to permit just that one directive.

```
AllowOverride Options=Indexes
```

Comment: Did you restart your server? Why include `Options Indexes` in your server config, only to disable this later in `.htaccess`?

Comment: How can i restart my server? i don't loose anything if i restart it right? (sorry for the noob question) I'm following tutorials, i just don't want my directories appear on my website..

Comment: You restart the _web_ server (ie. the Apache application), you don't need to restart the physical machine. The server config is only processed when Apache starts. So any changes to the server config only take effect when Apache is restarted.